# Accelerated electromagnetic system leads to divergent calculation?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

[image: paradox]

Consider the above system comprising a pair of oppositely charged parallel plates, connected by a rigid rod of length $r$, constrained to move in the x-direction.

The forces on the plates from the Coulomb electric fields and the magnetic forces are all in the vertical direction so that they do not affect the motion of the system.

The only fields that do affect the system are the horizontal radiation fields due to the acceleration of the charged plates.

Let us assume that we initially apply a force $F_0$ so that we have:

$$F_0 = m a_0$$

As charge $+q$ has an acceleration $a_0$ then it will produce a horizontal electric field at the negative plate given by:

$$E_+ = \frac{-qa_0}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c^2 r}$$

This will lead to a horizontal force $f_0$ on the negative plate, pointing towards the right, given by:

$$f_0 = \frac{q^2a_0}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c^2 r}$$

Likewise as charge $-q$ has an acceleration $a_0$ then it will produce a horizontal electric field at the positive plate given by:

$$E_- = \frac{qa_0}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c^2 r}$$

Again this will lead to a horizontal force $f_0$ on the positive plate, pointing towards the right, given by:

$$f_0 = \frac{q^2a_0}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c^2 r}$$

Thus the total force on the system is now given by:

$$F_1 = F_0 + 2f_0$$

Therefore the system has an increased acceleration given by:

$$a_1 = \frac{F_1}{m}$$

$$a_1 = a_0 \left(1+\frac{q^2}{2\pi\epsilon_0c^2rm}\right)$$

The argument can be repeated indefinitely leading to the calculated acceleration diverging exponentially.

What's gone wrong?

I think the best way to imagine the experiment is to simply drop the system in a gravitational field. The induced electric forces cause the system to accelerate faster than gravity which of course is forbidden by the equivalence principle.

There are no $\dot{a}$ terms in the calculation so I don't think the [Abraham-Lorentz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force) reaction force can save the day. A positive feedback involving forces and accelerations seems to preclude a consistent initial value for the acceleration.

Here's my (rather radical) solution: perhaps the mass has to change to ensure that the acceleration stays constant.

Perhaps we have:

$$F_0 = m_0 a_0$$

$$F_1 = m_1 a_0$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{m_1}{m_0} = \frac{F_1}{F_0}$$

$$ \frac{m_1}{m_0} = \frac{1}{m_0a_0}\left(m_0a_0+\frac{q^2a_0}{2\pi\epsilon_0c^2r}\right)$$

$$m_1 = m_0 + \frac{q^2}{2\pi\epsilon_0c^2r}$$

Comment: What does that mean "The argument can be repeated indefinitely leading to the calculated acceleration diverging exponentially"?

Comment: Where you encountered this problem?